# Cancel pending $http request

Tags: angular, typescript

I started working on a single page application with angular 6 and web API. I have a search box in it which searches data on key up event. I see the behavior that old response is loaded first and then the next responses which don’t look good on the slow connection. How can I cancel the pending search request every time key up is fired with new or less character.

Comment: You can use [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) with [distinctUntilChange](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged.html) to not query for each letter and to make sure that if the user writes a lot in sequence you'll only fire one request.

Comment: This page shows a good example https://medium.com/@nacimidjakirene/angular-search-autosuggest-with-observables-6f42987f80e6

Comment: Or [the angular docs have this example aswell](https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using observable for making http get request, you can cancel the subscription of previous http request before making new request i.e. on every keyup in your case.
In the example below, assume that the MyCustomSearchService is a service with a method `getSearchResult(searchText)` which returns an http response i.e. `return this.http.get(this.apiCallURL+searchText)`

```
export class MySinglePageAppComponent{
    private searchSubscription:any;//property that will store the search http subscription
    private searchText:string;//search text binded to your text box
    constructor(private myCustomSearchService: MyCustomSearchService) 
    {}
    //function called upon keyup
    getSearchValue(){
        //if already searched something then cancel its subscription.
        if(this.searchSubscription){
            this.searchSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        this.searchSubscription=this.myCustomSearchService.getSearchResult(this.searchText).subscribe((response)=>{
         let resultJSON=JSON.parse(response.json())
         //rest of the search hadler logic here
      });
    }
}
```

In this way, the previous pending requests will be cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

To cancel an ongoing request you can unsubscribe the observable. Even better, if you use a `switchMap` operator it will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KeyUp/KeyDown events to fire an event; in the event unsubscribe the request set as an observable.

KeyUp/KeyDown
https://angular.io/guide/user-input

unsubscribe:

```
let sub = this.http.get(url, {headers: reqHeaders})
        .subscribe(
            (res) => {
                ...
            }
        );

sub.unsubscribe();
```